# OSB : Xquery Comparision Failing Intermittently

Tags: xquery, osb, oracle-service-bus

I have following condition in my OSB proxy.

```
$body/*[1]/xyzflag eq 'true' and (:some other true conditions:)
```

The node `xyzflag` is not even present under node pointed by variable $body.

The condition works as expected (gives false) most of the times. but sometime it gives true.

Anyone has faced this situation? Seems a bug to me. Can some help?

Comment: Your XQuery expression does not seem to be valid (predicate without name test). Please make sure to _copy_ code, and not retype it; also post _working_ examples (read [how to post an SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org) about how a minimal example should look like). Also include example input for which the condition fails.

Comment: sorry for typo. I ate asterisk while trying to make it bold. correct expression is- $body/*[1]/customerId

Comment: Could you give an example value for $body where $body/*[1]/xyzflag eq 'true' evaluates to true unexpectedly?

Answer (score -1):

The XQuery expression you are trying is wrong.

e.g. If your XML is looks like below:

```
<school>
<teacher>
   <isClassteacher>Y</isClassteacher>
</teacher>  

<teacher>
  <isClassteacher>N</isClassteacher>
</teacher>
</school>
```

Then your expression will be like below:
data($body/teacher[1]/isClassteacher)='Y'

Note: Please make the changes as per your requirement.

Hope this will be helpful.

regards

Asutosh

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with his XPath expression.  $body/* selects all the child elements of $body, regardless of the name.  See https://www.w3.org/TR/xquery/#abbrev

Answer (score -1):

Try to make it like this:

**fn:data($body/[1]/xyzflag)**

Comment: eq will atomize arguments implicitly:
https://www.w3.org/TR/xquery/#id-value-comparisons
Adding fn:data isn't wrong but is unnecessary.

Answer (score -1):

If you are checking for existence of that node `<xyzflag>`, I will suggest you to use `fn:exists` function.

This expression

```
$body/*[1]/xyzflag = 'true'
```

will return true if the node `<xyzflag>` is present. It is not going to bother whether the contents of the node is present or not

Comment: $body/*[1]/xyzflag = 'true'  will not evaluate to true simply because <xyzflag> is present.  It will evaluate to true when the value of one of the xyzflag elements is equal to the string 'true'.  See https://www.w3.org/TR/xquery/#id-general-comparisons